# Program Execution by Operating System

Tags: operating-system

I am lot confused about the way operating system execute any program.Please help me with below queries.
Suppose we have a C program[wordCount.C] which read a text file and have 3 methods in it.
1. CalculateNumberOfwords()
2. CalculateMostUsedWord()
3. CalculateleastusedWord().

Now below are Question.
1. what will happen if we double click on the exe file[wordCount.exe] in terms of impact in RAM and processor.
2. How processor will start working on the program.
3. How and when text file data will be inserted into the RAM.
4. what if our ram is only 2GB and text file is 10GB.
5. Memory Managent[code segment , datasegment etc.]

So basically i want to know the complete flow of the program execution by OS.

Comment: depends on the OS, each OS has different implementation

Comment: a good computer architecture book would describe the process in detail, you might check out your local library for one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the operating system. The common elements are that executable files contains the instructions for the operating systems program loader. The executable file defines show the program is broken up into program sections. It will also define the starting address where to being execution.

In a modern system this process will just set up page tables. The data is not loaded until it is accessed.